# Javascript displaying but not calulating

Tags: javascript

This code, I have used many times before with out a problem. Instead of calculating parent.document.getElementById("itemscost").value + (1.3 * totalDistance) it is displaying the values together on the same line IE: it is displaying 20033.84 instead of calculating 200 + 33.84

```
parent.document.getElementById("costInput").value = (Math.round(((parent.document.getElementById("itemscost").value) + (1.3 * totalDistance)), 2));
```

Comment: HTML would help `parent.document` are you sure?

Comment: @zer00ne If the code is in a frame, `parent` accesses the page where the frame is located. HTML isn't needed, `parent.document.getElementById("itemscost").value` is always a string.